# Headphones with built-in mic

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones, headset

I have headphones that appear to have some kind of built-in mic, as well as a volume control and small button that may or may not control said mic. My machine has a headphone jack and a mic jack. When I plug the headphones in to the headphone jack, the mic doesn't work, and pressing the button while speaking into the mic doesn't help. When I plug them in to the mic jack, the headphones don't work.

The onboard audio card I'm using is simple but modern:

```
$ sudo lshw -c sound
  *-multimedia            
       description: Audio device
       product: Juniper HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5700 Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:83 memory:fea40000-fea43fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 40
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:16 memory:feb00000-feb03fff
```

PulseAudio is set to use the latter device, which is otherwise 100% working. Any ideas on how I would use the headphones' built-in mic?

Comment: answer in: https://superuser.com/questions/1312970/headset-microphone-not-detected-by-pulse-und-alsa

Comment: answer in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078911/smartphone-headset-microphone-not-working-only-internal-does

Answer (score 16):

It sounds like your headphones have a single jack that includes both the headphone and mic connections. This is called a "4-position" or "4-pin" connector. As you have discovered, unless your computer has a plug designed to use one of those connectors, only one or the other will work.

The 4-pin jacks are more common on smaller devices that benefit more from combining the two audio jacks into one. To find out if your computer has one of these 4-pin jacks, you could:

- Look at the marking on the jack to see if it has both headphone and mic icons, or an icon of a headset that shows both.
- Look up your computer/motherboard module, or info from `sudo lshw -c sound`, to see if the specs or discussions mention anything about this hardware having a 4-pin jack

If your computer doesn't have a 4-pin jack, a workaround would be an adapter that will plug into your headset, and then provide separate headphone and mic plugs for your computer. This will be something like a 3.5mm combo jack splitter, headset to PC.

Comment: Thanks! This answer is great and confirms a few of my suspicions but it would be even better if it also told me how to find out if my PC has one of these 4 pin connectors.

Comment: @Richard thanks for the feedback, I don't have a computer with a 4 pin connector, but I will try to update if I find more info about that.

Comment: They may be also be a issue in that is using the wrong [TRRS standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRRS#TRRS_standards), so does not electrically connect - however some headphones come with adapters to get round this.