# Smartphone headset microphone not working, only internal does

Tags: sound, 18.04, alsa, asus

I have ASUS X555SJ laptop, heaphones of smartphone, and combo port for both mic and headphones, but my PC keeps using internal mic and I am unable to change that. I have nothing in my System Settings, and tried with "Jack Retasking", "Pavucontrol", but unsuccesful. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
# cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC3236
Codec: Intel Braswell HDMI
```

Comment: Anyone? Anything?

Comment: Considering that only 15 folks have clicked on your question in 2 days, I counsel patience.

Comment: Heeeeeeeeeeeelp

Comment: Can you post an image of: goto settings -> sound -> click on input tab : make screenshot with alt+print

Comment: Post the output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, btw: did you blacklisted sth?

Comment: Post the output of `lspci -knn | grep -i audio -A2`

Comment: Settings/Sound/Input: https://i.imgur.com/1SarZE8.png
cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf: https://pastebin.com/tthQ6ydg
lspci -knn | grep -i audio -A2: https://pastebin.com/2AVT2PFE .... Thanks for finally replying to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved the problem. What I did to do so is I went to HDA Jack Retasking, selected Realtek codec, checked "Show unconnected pins" on the right panel, overrided Pin ID 0x18 & 0x19 with selection of Microphone, and applied settings on the bottom right.

[image: HDA Jack Retask]

After that, I went to pavucontrol > Input Devices and changed port to "Microphone (unplugged)":

[image: Pavuconrol]

and this actually solved my problem. Hope it helps someone! :)

Comment: This didn't work for me, but overriding just 0x19 did.

Comment: It worked for me on my Asus Vivobook with Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks!