# Headphone Mic not Working Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I have a Audio Technica MTX50BT with a standard 3.5mm jack. However, the mic doesnt seem to work. It defaults to the laptop mic. My laptop has 3 3.5mm ports, the headphone,mic,and combination ports.

I have tried https://superuser.com/questions/1312970/headset-microphone-not-detected-by-pulse-und-alsa but my realtek codec isnt found.

```
(base) ➜  ~ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC892
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
```

Realtek ALC892 does not exist in the link given. I tried ALC891, and the dell profile, but they dont work either. After undoing the changes to the conf, now the right side of my headphones dont have sound.

I have tried this link as well [Smartphone headset microphone not working, only internal does](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078911/smartphone-headset-microphone-not-working-only-internal-does) but it does not seem to work either.

This is borderline ridiculous. Getting an inbuilt mic on the headphone shouldnt be this hard..

Does anyone have any advice on this?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @YaroslavHavrylovych Nope. I decided to give up.

Comment: 1. At this point ALC892 already exists withing the given link (didn't help much to me). 2. My mic started to work when I put it into a dedicated mic port (using the splitter for jack).